# How to make mysql search for multiple keywords by relavance using mysql and php

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Hello I have a question regarding mysql search
I have a online product store with plenty of products and all the records have **keyword** field to store the keywords for searching purpose. data is like this

```
    A product_id=1  => keywords=laser wedding cake box
    B product_id=2  => keywords=red box
    C product_id=3  => keywords=laser card box
    D product_id=4  => keywords=wedding cake box etc....
```

If I search for `"laser wedding cake box"` my requirement is, it should result the below
first it should return all the records containing

- all four words
- then all records with 3 words
- then all records with 2 words
- then all records with each words

**all the result should append to query according to the given order**

I have using `FULLTEXT with BOOLEAN MODE`. it is working for four words but i cant append the rest.

Can you guys please give me some light for this requirement
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't put all the keywords in a single field. Use a table with one row per keyword, and a foreign key to the product table. Then you can use `COUNT()` to count the number of rows that match.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the quick reply. Didn't get you right. can you explain it little more.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a separate row for each keyword, not all keywords in the same row.

```
CREATE TABLE product_keywords (
    product_id INT,
    keyword VARCHAR(100),
    UNIQUE KEY (product_id, keyword),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (product_id)
);

INSERT INTO product_keywords (product_id, keyword) VALUES
(1, 'laser'), (1, 'wedding'), (1, 'cake'), (1, 'box'),
(2, 'red'), (2, 'box'),
(3, 'laser'), (3, 'card'), (3, 'box'),
(4, 'wedding', (4, 'cake'), (4, 'box');
```

Then you can use a query like:

```
SELECT p.name, p.product_id, COUNT(*) AS num_matches
FROM products AS p
JOIN product_keywords AS k ON p.product_id = k.product_id
WHERE k.keyword IN ('laser', 'wedding', 'cake', 'box')
ORDER BY num_matches DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really appreciate your work. What happen if someone search "boxes" instead of "box" which i gave to my keyword. I am not sure it will return the records of "box" without using any LIKE statement or something

Comment: That's more complicated, and full-text search would probably be more appropriate if you want to support that in a general way.

Comment: Otherwise, you see something like `WHERE 'box' LIKE CONCAT(k.keyword, '%') OR 'laser' LIKE CONCAT(k.keyword, '%') OR 'wedding' CONCAT(k.keyword, '%') OR 'cake' LIKE CONCAT(k.keyword, '%')`